# onClick method execution error while trying to get calculation result from a class to Main Activity onclick method to set a textfield

Tags: android-studio, class, methods, onclick, fatal-error

I have tried to create a class that make a specific calculation. The variables shall be taken from Main Activity and result shall be taken from class and a text field shall be set by an on-click method in Main Activity. However from the error message I understand that app is crashed because on-click method  can not be executed resulting from an internal call. I have tried couple of changes in my code but I am still not able to over come this error.

Main Activity code is:

```
 public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

//Viewportların tanımları
EditText pressure, corrosionAllowance, result, allowableStress, materialDiameter, materialThickness, jointFactor;
//Objecte aktarılacak variable'lar
String designPressureS, corrosionAllowanceS, allowableStressS, materialDiameterS, materialThicknessS, jointFactorS;
Shell shell;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    //Viewprotlara atıyorum
    pressure = findViewById(R.id.pressure);
    designPressureS = String.valueOf(pressure);

    corrosionAllowance = findViewById(R.id.corrosionAllowance);
    corrosionAllowanceS = String.valueOf(corrosionAllowance);

    allowableStress = findViewById(R.id.allowableStress);
    allowableStressS = String.valueOf(allowableStress);

    materialDiameter = findViewById(R.id.materialDiameter);
    materialDiameterS = String.valueOf(materialDiameter);

    materialThickness = findViewById(R.id.materialThickness);
    materialThicknessS = String.valueOf(materialThickness);

    jointFactor = findViewById(R.id.jointFactor);
    jointFactorS = String.valueOf(jointFactor);

    result = findViewById(R.id.result);

    shell = new Shell(allowableStressS,materialDiameterS,materialThicknessS,jointFactorS,designPressureS,corrosionAllowanceS);


}

public void calculation(View view){

    String resultS = String.format("%.2f",shell.thickness());
    result.setText(resultS);

}
```

}
And this the class:

```
public class Shell {

String materialSMYS, outerDiameter, materialThickness, jointFactor, pressure, corrosionAllowance;
double designPressureD, corrosionAllowanceD, allowableStressD, materialDiameterD, materialThicknessD, jointFactorD, result;

public Shell(String materialSMYS, String outerDiameter, String materialThickness, String jointFactor, String pressure, String corrosionAllowance){

this.materialSMYS = materialSMYS;
this.outerDiameter = outerDiameter;
this.materialThickness = materialThickness;
this.jointFactor = jointFactor;
this.pressure = pressure;
this.corrosionAllowance = corrosionAllowance;

}

public double thickness(){

designPressureD = Double.parseDouble(pressure);
corrosionAllowanceD = Double.parseDouble(corrosionAllowance);
allowableStressD = Double.parseDouble(materialSMYS);
materialDiameterD = Double.parseDouble(outerDiameter);
materialThicknessD = Double.parseDouble(materialThickness);
jointFactorD = Double.parseDouble(jointFactor);

result = this.designPressureD*this.materialDiameterD/ (this.allowableStressD*this.jointFactorD - 0.6*designPressureD);

return result;
```

}
}

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have handled the situation with lots of changes in my code:
1- All String.valueOf have been changed to getText().toString() and all of them have been transported to onclick method
2- Shell.class has been entirely changed. A simple class has been written.
3- shell object creation has been transported into onclick method.
And this is my final Main Activity Code:

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

//Viewportların tanımları
EditText pressure, corrosionAllowance, allowableStress, materialDiameter, materialThickness, jointFactor;
TextView result;
//Objecte aktarılacak variable'lar
String designPressureS, corrosionAllowanceS, allowableStressS, materialDiameterS, materialThicknessS, jointFactorS;
Shell shell;
double designPressureD, corrosionAllowanceD, allowableStressD, materialDiameterD, materialThicknessD, jointFactorD;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    //Viewprotlara atıyorum
    pressure = findViewById(R.id.pressure);

    corrosionAllowance = findViewById(R.id.corrosionAllowance);

    allowableStress = findViewById(R.id.allowableStress);

    materialDiameter = findViewById(R.id.materialDiameter);

    materialThickness = findViewById(R.id.materialThickness);

    jointFactor = findViewById(R.id.jointFactor);

    result = findViewById(R.id.result);

}

public void calculation(View view){

    try {

        designPressureS =pressure.getText().toString();
        corrosionAllowanceS = corrosionAllowance.getText().toString();
        allowableStressS = allowableStress.getText().toString();
        materialDiameterS = materialDiameter.getText().toString();
        materialThicknessS = materialThickness.getText().toString();
        jointFactorS = jointFactor.getText().toString();

        designPressureD = Double.parseDouble(designPressureS);
        corrosionAllowanceD = Double.parseDouble(corrosionAllowanceS);
        allowableStressD = Double.parseDouble(allowableStressS);
        materialDiameterD = Double.parseDouble(materialDiameterS);
        materialThicknessD = Double.parseDouble(materialThicknessS);
        jointFactorD = Double.parseDouble(jointFactorS);

        shell = new Shell();

        double resultD = shell.thickness(allowableStressD,materialDiameterD,jointFactorD, designPressureD,corrosionAllowanceD);
        String resultS =String.format("%.2f",resultD);
        result.setText(resultS);
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();

    }


}
```

And this my final shell.class

```
public class Shell {

public double thickness(double materialSMYS, double outerDiameter, double jointFactor, double pressure, double corrosionAllowance){
return (pressure*outerDiameter/(materialSMYS*jointFactor-0.6*pressure))+corrosionAllowance;}}
```